# Is it possible to save drawing which is drawed in Google Slides with high DPI?

Tags: png, jpeg, google-slides

Recently I write the research paper, So, I need the high resolution picture.

I did all of my research in Google Slides but Google Slides didn't support for function "Save as picture".

Moreover, If I copy the drawing which is drawed in Google Slides and paste it Google Docs, it doesn't paste all of it, just "text" in that drawing.

Are there any way to save drawing in Google Slides with high DPI picture(like png, jpg anything)?

Thanks for your help. always.

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can I ask you about the value of DPI you want?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just want to change the value of DPI, like over 300. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I forgot to ask one more question. How about the width and height (pixels) of the image?

Comment: Thanks for your help again. the width and height of the image should be similar with original one. If the width and the height of the drawing in Google slide which I want to copy are 100, 300 each, the width and height of image will be same. thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The image which is exported at Google APIs has the resolution of 72 DPI. So when you want to convert this to 300 DPI, the base size is required to expand to 4.17 times. After the expanded image was obtained, it converts the image to the original size and 300 DPI. I think that it can achieve what you want by this flow. How about this flow? If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration and help. If I had few drawing in my Google Slides file, the solution you mentioned will work. However I have a lot of drawing(over 30 drawing), it can be a tedious work.

Comment: And also, if there are no solution to do it, you solution will be very good choice. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that I could understand about what you want to do. When there are many slides, I recommend to create a script. You can use Slides API. So you can use Google Apps Script and other languages. Can I ask you about the language you want to use?

Comment: Each slide can be obtained as images with the large size by using the method of [presentations.pages.getThumbnail](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/getThumbnail) in Slides API. In my workaround, I suppose that I use this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think there are still some problem. The drawing that I want to save as high resolution image is made in Google Slide. It means it is drawing object that mixed with things(like arrow, line, rectangle and so on). In powerpoint, just copy and paste it to anywhere or click "save it as a picture", but in Google Slides it can be.

Comment: Or if I increase the base size of drawing, I can get better resolution image. However, If I increased the base size of it, the text size in the drawing is still small. So, I should increase the base size, and change all text size in the drawing. Maybe it can be more tedious work. Thanks for you help a lot. Really appreciate it.

Comment: You want to create a part of a slide as an image. Is my understanding correct? And when the large image is retrieved from a slide using Slides API, all objects are linearly expanded. So it is not required to adjust the size of font. I worry whether I misunderstand your situation.

Comment: Yes, I apologize make you misunderstand. I want to create a part of a slide as a high resolution image. You mean that if I use Slides API, is it possible to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187036/discussion-between-tanaike-and-frhyme).

Answer (score 7):

I found a better and easier way to get high-resolution image from Google Slides.

Just, In file menu => page setup(or setting) => increase the size of slide.

If you make it larger, you can extract each slide as high-resolution image.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer above with more detailed steps (as of current version of Google Slides):

1. In your slides file, Go to menu option File > Page Setup
2. In the popup box that appears, choose "custom" size from the dropdown
3. Set the new size to larger than the current settings, making sure to preserve the aspect ratio (for example, this sets up a slide image with 16:9 aspect ratio but twice the width and height)
   [image: Page Setup dialog box with doubled size for 16:9 aspect ratio Google slide]
4. Click "Apply"
5. Go back to File menu, choose "Download," and select one of the current-slide image format options, like JPG or PNG.

Changing the size in Page Setup before downloading your current slide as an image will give you a larger default download size.